# Questions about Dynamically Generating Robots.txt Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

From [Dynamically Generating Robots.txt Using ASP.NET MVC](http://rehansaeed.com/dynamically-generating-robots-txt-using-asp-net-mvc/):

1. > Fortunately, it’s really easy to dynamically create a robots.txt file,
   >   which auto-generates the site-map URL using the MVC UrlHelper. Take a
   >   look at the code below:
   >
   > **Dynamically Generated robots.txt using ASP.NET MVC**
   >
   > ```
   > public class HomeController : Controller
   > {
   >     [Route("robots.txt", Name = "GetRobotsText"), OutputCache(Duration = 86400)]
   >     public ContentResult RobotsText()
   >     {
   >         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   >         stringBuilder.AppendLine("user-agent: *");
   >         stringBuilder.AppendLine("disallow: /error/");
   >         stringBuilder.AppendLine("allow: /error/foo");
   >         stringBuilder.Append("sitemap: ");
   >         stringBuilder.AppendLine(this.Url.RouteUrl("GetSitemapXml", null,
   >             this.Request.Url.Scheme).TrimEnd('/'));
   >         return this.Content(stringBuilder.ToString(), "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
   >     }
   >     [Route("sitemap.xml", Name = "GetSitemapXml"), OutputCache(Duration = 86400)]
   >     public ContentResult SitemapXml()
   >     {
   >         // I'll talk about this in a later blog post.
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   - Does the timing for creating robots.txt referred to by "dynamically" here mean the same timing as "dynamic" in "dynamic web
     pages" created by JavaScript programs?
   - Which namespaces and .dll files are the classes `controller` and `ContentResult` defined?
2. > Creating a route ending with a file extension is not allowed by
   >   default in ASP.NET MVC. To get around this security restriction, you
   >   need to add the following to the Web.config file:
   >
   > **Web.config Handler to Allow Robots.txt**
   >
   > ```
   > XHTML
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   > <configuration>
   >   <!-- ...Omitted -->
   >   <system.webServer>
   >     <!-- ...Omitted -->
   >     <handlers>
   >       <!-- ...Omitted -->
   >       <add name="RobotsText"
   >            path="robots.txt"
   >            verb="GET"
   >            type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
   >            preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
   >     </handlers>
   >   </system.webServer>
   > </configuration>
   > ```

   - When is `Web.config` read, and when does its content take effect? Does editing the `Web.config` file above imply the timing of creating robots.txt is dynamic?
   - If I manually add robots.txt file, do i have to edit `Web.config` file?

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult

Comment: Thanks, @SLaks What is the timing of creating robots.txt? How is the timing relative to the dynamic web pages created by JavaScript programs?

Comment: As far as I can tell the "file" is created every single time it is requested, and it is the creation that is dynamic. The file does not exist on disk anywhere, it is created in memory then shipped to the destination then removed from memory. The "timing" of creation is also dynamic but so is every single web request; the author is referring to the creation of the file when they use the term "dynamic", even your quote says so: "it’s really easy to *dynamically create* a robots.txt file".